# I am trying to set up django signals to let someone get noticed after creating a blog

Tags: django, django-signals

but this code does not work... keep error message like 'TypeError at /blog/create/

Here are the codes I put at blog/signals.py

```
@receiver(signals.post_save, sender=Post)
def send_mail(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    print('signal send')

    subject = "Thank you"
    message = Post.objects.get(??)
    send_mail(subject, 'message', '',
              ['info@*****.com.au'], fail_silently=False, )
```

?? is the problem... I put pk=pk, pk=id, I don't know what parameter I need to put here...

Comment: When I put 'pk=pk' , but it says there; "name 'pk' is not defined" "NameError"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to explicitly get the `Post`, you already have it as the `instance` parameter sent to the signal (as per the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/signals/#post-save)):

> `instance`
> The actual instance being saved.

Comment: Read the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/email/#send-mail

Comment: Try e.g. `send_mail(subject=subject, message='message', from_email=None, recipient_list=['info@*****.com.au'])`

Comment: Rename your `def send_mail()` to something else. You're overwriting the name of the Django library function.

Comment: AKX >> Thank you so much. Now I see what you mean by "Rename your ''''def send_mail()````                   send_mail() and send mail again on the next paragraph might have django get confused... I changed the name of definition to 'notify_user' then it works!!! Thanks again